# How to setup a proper equinox installation

Tags: osgi, equinox

I googled this for hours but I couldn't find anything useful.
I have developed some OSGi bundles and now I want to run them outside of the Eclipse IDE in the equinox container, but it always throws an exception:

```
!SESSION 2011-01-03 14:26:58.958 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_CH
Framework arguments:  -Dosgi.clean=true -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -console;
Command-line arguments:  -consoleLog -Dosgi.clean=true -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -console;

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-01-03 14:26:59.567
!MESSAGE Error starting bundle: initial@reference:file:javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915.jar/
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: A fragment bundle cannot be started: javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915 [49]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleFragment.startWorker(BundleFragment.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startBundle(EclipseStarter.java:1133)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startBundles(EclipseStarter.java:1126)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.loadBasicBundles(EclipseStarter.java:646)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:301)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:150)
init dd core...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-01-03 14:26:59.773
!MESSAGE Bundle javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915 [49] is not active.
```

(the "init dd core..." text comes properly from my project.)

I have the following file structure:

```
+configuration
 +config.ini
+ch.thobens.dd.commands_1.0.0.jar
+ch.thobens.dd.common.items_1.0.0.jar
+ch.thobens.dd.core_1.0.0.jar
+ch.thobens.dd.game_1.0.0.jar
+javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915.jar
+org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20100505-1235.jar
+org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.0.v20100515.jar
+org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.200.v20100517.jar
+org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.3.0.v20100520/runtime_registry_compatibility.jar
+org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.6.0.v20100505.jar
+org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.0.v20100512.jar
+org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503.jar
+org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.3.0.v20100503.jar
+org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.0.v20100503.jar
+org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.2.100.v20100503.jar
+org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar
```

and my config.ini file has the following contents:

```
osgi.bundles=javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915.jar@start, org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20100505-1235.jar@start, org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.0.v20100515.jar@start, org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.200.v20100517.jar@start,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.3.0.v20100520/runtime_registry_compatibility.jar@start, org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.6.0.v20100505.jar@start, org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.0.v20100512.jar@start, org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503.jar@2:start, org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.3.0.v20100503.jar@start, org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.0.v20100503.jar@start, org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.2.100.v20100503.jar@start, ch.thobens.dd.commands_1.0.0.jar@start, ch.thobens.dd.common.items_1.0.0.jar@start, ch.thobens.dd.core_1.0.0.jar@start, ch.thobens.dd.game_1.0.0.jar@1:start
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
osgi.noShutdown=true
```

The bundles that are listed here are the same bundles that are selected if I select "Add required Plug-ins" in the run configuration. If I run these bundles from the Eclipse PDE, it works fine.

Additionally, there is no difference between running the command

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar -consoleLog -Dosgi.clean=true -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true
```

and when I use the equinox launcher (via eclipse.exe).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution (through the eclipse product exporter):

The javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915.jar is not an OSGi bundle itself, it's an OSGi framework extension.

I had to change the config.ini file:

1. Remove the entry for the
   javax_transaction bundle in the
   property osgi.bundles
2. added the following line:

   osgi.framework.extensions=javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201006150915.jar

Comment: Actually it looks like javax.transaction is a fragment bundle. You could have left it in the osgi.bundles list, just remove the `@start`. But anyway I would not expect the error to be fatal, so you could have continued to run the application. It just doesn't look nice to have exceptions like that in the log ;-)